# Looking for a sci-fi novel about a private investigator in a parallel world

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read the book in German maybe 30 years ago. The story is about a private investigator that can enter a parallel world via his cabinet. There his assistant is a female sentient gorilla. His friend, a female actor(?) was temporarily turned into a fighter space ship. The plot partially plays in a hollowed-out asteroid that is built and inhabited by sentient whales and dolphins.

I did research on Google and ChatGpt, but apart from ever-repeatimg hints to David Brin's Uplift series (which is not the right thing)… I found nought.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly *[The Venus Belt](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1785640)* (1980) by L. Neil Smith, the the second book in the [*North American Confederacy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Neil_Smith#North_American_Confederacy_series) series.

Parts that match:
The story is about a private investigator that can enter a parallel world via his cabinet.

> Match.  Edwin "Win" Bear is a Denver police officer turned private detective. In the Venus Belt he travels between the worlds using a probability broach in a back closet/room/office.

There his assistant is a female sentient gorilla.

> Match. In the parallel worlds apes (including gorillas) are sentient.  His assistant is a female.

His friend, a female actor(?) was temporarily turned into a fighter space ship.

> Partial match.  His friend Lucy Kropotkin is loaded into a mobile 'droid body, not a fighter ship.

The plot partially plays in a hollowed-out asteroid that is built and inhabited by sentient whales and dolphins.

> Match. Has some great descriptions of how it is built and works.

[image]

Comment: An excellent find. I've added a copy of the cover that's most likely to be the one that OP saw

Comment: The ideal antidote to *Hamilton*.